# swap icons by adding class to element only in pure CSS

Tags: html, css, icons

I have a page than contain a read more button. When click on it, display some hidden content. Next to this button I have an icon represent by an arrow up or down in function if the button is set to show more or less. I take icons from library which allow to take them by the only way of class (not by link). I want  to swap this icon according if read more or less. **I can't use JavaScript**. Is there any solution in order to add some class to an element only **in pure CSS** or any solution that can solve this issue?

```css
.read_more_txt {
  display: none;
}

#read_more_checkbox {
  display: none;
}

#read_more_checkbox:checked~.read_more_txt {
  display: block;
}

.read_more_label {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#read_more_checkbox~.read_more_label:before {
  content: attr(read_more);
}

#read_more_checkbox:checked~.read_more_label::before {
  content: attr(read_less);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="read_more_checkbox">
<label for="read_more_checkbox" class="read_more_label" read_more="Show more" read_less="Show less">
    <span class="ico-arrow ico-angle-down"></span>
    <span class="ico-arrow ico-angle-down ico-angle-up"></span>
    </label>
<div class="read_more_txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam possimus ad necessitatibus quas veritatis. At accusantium enim praesentium nihil porro consequatur aperiam quia fuga adipisci in, incidunt velit fugiat laborum.</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Nope, CSS is read-only. It does not execute scripts (with tiny exceptions such as animation). However, under no circumstances, it is able to add or remove classes from an element. For that, you need a script. What you can do though is to hide an element if a checkbox is `:checked`

Comment: Perhaps there is any way using background image or something like that

Comment: same issue. Your only chance is to use the `:checked` pseudo-selector to hide and show an element when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: tacoshy has the right answer. I’d like to provide two improvements to think about, though:
a) [Use data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead of invalid attributes like `read_more`.
b) Consider using the [`<detail>` and `<summary>` elements](https://www.scottohara.me/blog/2018/09/03/details-and-summary.html), which work with assistive technology as well and don’t exclude users with disabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the `:checked` pseudo-selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) to check if the `checkbox` is checked or not and then hide/show the span by means of the [Adjacent sibling selector `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).

```css
.ico-angle-up {
  display: none;
}

#read_more_checkbox:checked + label[for="read_more_checkbox"] > .ico-angle-up {
  display: inline;
}

#read_more_checkbox:checked + label[for="read_more_checkbox"] > .ico-angle-down {
  display: none;
}


/* original css*/
.read_more_txt {
  display: none;
}

#read_more_checkbox {
  display: none;
}

#read_more_checkbox:checked~.read_more_txt {
  display: block;
}

.read_more_label {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#read_more_checkbox~.read_more_label:before {
  content: attr(read_more);
}

#read_more_checkbox:checked~.read_more_label::before {
  content: attr(read_less);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="read_more_checkbox">
<label for="read_more_checkbox" class="read_more_label" read_more="Show more" read_less="Show less">
    <span class="ico-arrow ico-angle-down">&darr;</span>
    <span class="ico-arrow ico-angle-up">&uarr;</span>
    </label>
<div class="read_more_txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam possimus ad necessitatibus quas veritatis. At accusantium enim praesentium nihil porro consequatur aperiam quia fuga adipisci in, incidunt velit fugiat laborum.</div>
```

Comment: @Andy while I believe that your edit was done with good intentions, it is commentary. If you want to add your own opinion to a solution then you must use the comment option but not edit it into another user's answer! Especially in this case the OP clearly asked for a CSS-only solution as JS can't be used. As such your whole edit is not applicable in this case (despite the fact that it is commentary don't he post).